# PayPal window is not closing and onApprove is not called

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-buttons

I had a working PayPal flow for buying subscription using PayPal buttons. User had to click the button, PayPal window opened, after filling all the data, PayPal window disappear, onApprove hook was fired and I can handle the rest in my code.

But for few days, flow changed, and now, when user enters correct data, PayPal windows is not closing by itself, but showing information what user bought, who is the seller, how to remove subscription. onApprove hook is not fired, so I can't handle the result. All user can do, is close popup by himself, but then onCancel hook is called, instead onApprove.

Payments are proceeding correctly, following webhooks are handled by backend etc. I just don't know what happened to my onApprove hook.

Comment: This happens to me too but only if a subscription is created without a paypal account. If I log in with a sandbox account and create the subscription everything works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a paypal bug which has now been [fixed](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1544)